# Perl and PostgreSQL escaping $

Tags: perl, postgresql

I have an SQL statement executed from perl.

```
$my_sql = qq (
            SELECT 1 AS ....
            );
```

Then I do

```
my $sm = $dbh->prepare($my_sql);
   $sm->execute;
```

The issue is that my SQL has regex like this in many places.

```
value ~ '^[1-9][0-9]?/[1-9][0-9]?/[1-9][0-9]{3}$':
```

So I get errors when I execute the perl script because of these '$'.

```
Use of uninitialized value $' in concatenation (.) or string at
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: execute called with an unbound placeholder at
```

How can I avoid these errors and make the SQL statement work?

Comment: Do you really need `qq`?

Comment: Use `q()` instead to avoid interpolation of variables. `?` will also need to be escaped, check the documentation for `DBI` for how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qq(something)` is just another way to say `"something"` while `q(something)` means `'something'`.

The difference between `"this"` and `'this'` is interpolation, which is enabled only inside double quotes.

```
my $foo = 123;
print "<< $foo >>";  # prints << 123 >>
print '<< $foo >>';  # prints << $foo >>
```

So, since `$` is not special symbol inside `''`, just change `qq` to `q`.